# reset password win server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, password-reset

I have windows server 2012 R2 in front of me and I just can log into the server from an account that is NOT the administrator. I don't have any domain running on the server and the server is mostly file server and sage server. I need to get administrator privileges. I tried Hiren, password reset disk (which is created by my current user which is not admin), and booting up with win server 2012 r2 media. none of them are working. can anyone help we in this fact?

Comment: There are several tools (usually in form of bootable ISOs) that can reset passwords on local accounts; they are usually meant for client OSes, but will work on server OSes as well, as long as the account you are trying to access is a local one and not a domain one.

Comment: it is a local account. I tried several of them and none of them worked. do you know any one which you are already tested

Comment: I tried Hiren, but when it wants to list the users from SAM file from c:\windows\system32\config it says you dont have permission

Comment: Sorry, haven't used them in a while, I'm not up to speed on this specific topic. But I know there are several ones. Try something Linux-based, they happily bypass NTFS permissions.